# Print a Chinese character in Jupyter notebook (Python 3)

Tags: python, unicode, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to print the character 維 in a Jupyter notebook. I can do it using the following code

```
w = '\xe7\xb6\xad'

print( bytes(w, encoding='raw-unicode-escape').decode('utf-8') )
```

However, I only have the string `z` where

```
z = '\\xe7\\xb6\\xad'
```

I have tried the following solutions from other questions on SO.

```
print( bytes(z, encoding='raw-unicode-escape').decode('utf-8') )

print( z.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape') )

import codecs
u = codecs.decode(z, 'raw-unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')
print(u)

print( str(u.decode('utf-8')) )

bytes( str(u.decode('utf-8')), encoding='raw-unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')
```

None of them prints 維.

How can I print 維 if I only start with `z`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way

```
bytes.fromhex(z.replace('\\x', '')).decode('utf-8')
```